# Extended file globbing not working with cat inside bash script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, wildcards

When, in my terminal, I type

```
cat ~/my/+(a|b)/doc
```

It reads ok from both ~/my/a/doc and ~/my/b/doc, but when I put that command in a `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat ~/my/'+(a|b)'/doc
```

I get the error:

```
cat: ~/my/+(a|b)/doc: No such file or directory
```

Is it not possible to use extended globbing inside a `bash` script?

Comment: `+(a|b)` shouldn't be 'quoted' in your script; that suppresses evaluation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to turn on `extglob`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
cat ~/my/+(a|b)/doc
```

`+()` is an extended pattern, is only recognized when `extglob` is enabled.
By default `extglob` is on in interactive shells and off in non-interactive shells.

Comment: right on the spot! thanks a lot @manatwork :)